# AS3 Change textfield inside movieclip added from library

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield, addchild

I'm trying to do the following:

I have an empty movieClip in my stage called **zonaCentral_mc**. I use a function that has this code:

```
zonaCentral_DescripcionProceso = new zonaCentral_DescripcionProceso_mc();
zonaCentral_mc.addChild(zonaCentral_DescripcionProceso);
```

It loads the MovieClip **zonaCentral_DescripcionProceso** from the library into the empty movieclip **zonaCentral_mc**. The loaded MC has a dynamic textfield called **titulo_text** inside. How can I change that text? I'm trying:

```
this["zonaCentral_mc"].getChildByName("zonaCentral_DescripcionProceso").getChildByName("titulo_text").text = "hello";
```

but I get the error: **#1010: One term is not defined and has no properties**

I've also tried the **dot** notation **this["zonaCentral_mc"].zonaCentral_DescripcionProceso.titulo_text.text** with the same result.

Am I accessing it the wrong way? Why isn't it defined, I believe that they're all defined and in the stage when I call the above statement.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `this["zonaCentral_mc"]` style of noting the movieclip. Have you tried just using `zonaCentral_mc`?  I would try tracing out your line one item at a time. First `zonaCentral_mc`, the `zonaCentral_mc.getChildByName("zonaCentral_DescripcionProceso")`, etc, and see where the problem is.

Comment: Hi Sam, thank you for your reply, the problem was that the loaded MC didn't have an instance name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the MovieClip you instantiate doesn't have an instance name, that's why you can't access it through "getChildByName".

Try this:

```
zonaCentral_DescripcionProceso.name = "zonaCentralChildClip";
...
this["zonaCentral_mc"].getChildByName("zonaCentralChildClip").titulo_text.text = "hello";
```

But also, I am pretty sure you can access the text field as well:

```
zonaCentral_DescripcionProceso.titulo_text.text = "hello";
```

Please note, if you're `zonaCentral_DescripcionProceso` is a MovieClip, you can access the text field without the "getChildByName" method.

Cheers,
Rob

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried the second option and it works. I thought that since **zonaCentral_DescripcionProceso** was a child of **zonaCentral_mc**, I had to access the child through the parent when using the dot notation. I also didn't know that I had to specify the instance name, I assumed that I would take the variable name used when created. Well, I learned something more today :)

Comment: Well, if you have nested clips the instance name is very useful. In this case you can leave it as you can access your instance through the zonaCentral_DescripcionProceso variable.

Comment: what if in 1st solution zonaCentral_mc is in inside a movieClip instance-named mcA?? then this["mcA.zonaCentral_mc"].getChild doesn't work! any ideas?