# How to access MC inside movieclip added from library?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have the following code and I followed [the answer from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588174/as3-change-textfield-inside-movieclip-added-from-libray), but it doesn't seem to be working for me. I'm not getting an error or getting a trace response.

Basically I need to access this `test_mc` inside the added child. Am I doing something wrong?

```
for (var i:int=0; i<30; i++) {
    var mc:panelClass = new panelClass();
    all_mc.addChild(mc);
    mc.x = allWidth * i;

    // Accessing the test mc
    mc.test_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ctaOnClickHandler);

}
function ctaOnClickHandler(e:MouseEvent) {
    trace("Clicked");
}
```

Comment: Try this within the loop and see if it works (under the addEventListener or something):: trace(mc.test_mc);

Comment: have you assign instance name for test_mc inside panelClass in property panel ????????

Answer (score 0):

Kind of hard to answer this without know what panelClass is and how it is built. I'm assuming test_mc is a movieclip that's using all it's default properties and is on the display list of panelClass and since there are no errors it's been instantiated. The only think I can think of is there anything being displayed on top of test_mc inside panelClass?

Comment: Hi toad013, panelClass is a movieClip with some text mcs and image mcs inside. test_mc is a button mc inside the panelClass, and it is at the very top inside panelClass. Hope that helps with the confusion?

Comment: just to clarify. the problem is the ctaOnClickHandler is not being executed correct?